# Request to Machine Learning service on Bluemix using Python

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, spss-modeler

I'm struggling in find a way to send data and have back the prediction of a SPSS model deployed on Bluemix Machine Learning service.

I make a lot of test using request library in Python or with curl command but I did not succeed.

I'm too new to Bluemix to understand the service documentation.

Any help,

Thanks

Comment: I am puzzled by your comment about "too new to Bluemix to understand the service documentation." Can you elaborate? If you have suggestions for the documentation, you can always submit feedback here: https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/

Comment: You are right Bill,what I meant is that I lack of experience in using Bluemix services and then some concepts in the documentation are to me unknown

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted to be sure that the documentation for it needed to be improved to increase clarity. If you see something, please be sure to submit feedback.

Comment: Absolutely I will do it Bill ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pass data in and receive the prediction with the code as follows:

```
import requests, urllib3, json

access_key= "INSERT_ACCESS_KEY_HERE"
username = "INSERT_USERNAME_HERE"
password = "INSERT_PASSWORD_HERE"
headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='{}:{}'.format(username, password))

payload_online= {  "tablename": "INSERT_TABLENAME_HERE",  "header": [INSERT_TABLE_HEADERS_HERE],"data": [[INSERT_DATA_TO_USE_FOR_THE_PREDICTION_HERE]]}

url= 'https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/pm/v1/score/INSERT_CONTEXTID_HERE?accesskey=INSERT_THE_ACCESS_KEY'

header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': "INSERT_TOKEN_HERE"}


response_online = requests.post(url, json=payload_online, headers=header)

print(response_online.text)
```